# Confused with the following type casting in c#

Tags: c#, .net, casting

```
class B{
// Base class
}

class D : B{
//Derived class from B
}

//create objects
B b1 = new B();
D d1 = new D();

//why the following is not right?
D d2 = (D) b1;
```

//will the following be right?
    B b1 = d1;

Then why does the following work :

```
class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        double x = 1234.7;
        int a;
        a = (int)x;  // cast double to int
        System.Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
}
```

Besides what use is the concept of casting then if we can't cast a base class object to a derived class object?

Comment: Because `B` is not `D`... next question

Comment: D derives from B so D is also B. Not the other way around.

Comment: Also, your example shows nothing about `D` being derived from anything

Comment: Your code doesn't show D deriving from B.

Comment: But then why is the following code right :                              class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        double x = 1234.7;
        int a;
        a = (int)x;  // cast double to int
        System.Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
}

Comment: ahhhh... now that is something different. That is called explicit casting ([read more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)). you can implement that on your own classes too ([see this for more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a(v=vs.80).aspx))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `B` is not derived from `D`.

Key example of why this is a problem would be what if D defined a new field or property.  b1 would have no implementation of this and no the storage for the field value.

Answer (score 3):

Because `D` is not derived from `B`. Hell, even if it was, you could only go from `D` to `B`, not the other way.

This is because they are completely separate classes. The fact that they have the exact same properties (none) changed **nothing.**

Comment: i was actually getting confused as : if 'int' can be casted to biggies then itself like 'double' , then why can't it be possible in the mentioned case, anyway got the difference now , understood what explicit and implicit cast actually mean

Answer (score 2):

Because `D` is not a derived class. *Comments do not affect the code* ;-)

As it stands they are in no way related, so C# has no idea how to cast a `B` to a `D`.

Changing it to a be derived class might be a good idea:

```
class D : B {
//...
}
```

You still will not be able to cast a base class to a more specific class though.

Comment: Thank you , i was actually getting confused as : if 'int' can be casted to biggies then itself like 'double' , then why can't it be possible in the mentioned case, anyway got the difference now , understood what explicit and implicit cast actually mean